# A theorem about the Poisson Point process.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

In the proof of the Levy-Khintchine theorem, I saw a theorem about the Poisson
point process.

The theorem states that if $\Pi$ is a poission point process on $S$ with
intensity measure $\mu.$ Let $f:S\rightarrow\lbrack0,\infty)$ be a measurable
function. And define
$$
Z=\int_{S}f\left(  x\right)  \Pi\left(  dx\right)
$$

We have the following,

$$
E\left[  Z\right]  =\int_{S}f\left(  x\right)  \mu\left(  dx\right)
$$

and if $E\left[  Z\right]  <\infty,$ then,

$$
Var\left(  Z\right)  =\int_{S}f\left(  x\right)  ^{2}\mu\left(  dx\right)
$$

How should I proof this? I'm thinking about started the proof by assuming $f$ is a
simple function, and apply DCT somehow? Are there any proofs for this theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is given in Proposition 19.5 in *Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by Ken Iti Sato. It goes along the lines:

1. Show that $Z$ follows a Compound Poisson Process with characteristic function
   $$
   \varphi_Y(z):={\rm E}[e^{izY}]=\exp\left(\int_S(e^{izf(x)}-1)\,\mu(\mathrm dx)\right),\quad z\in\mathbb{R}.
   $$
2. Use the [derivatives of the characeristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Properties) to obtain expressions of the first and second moment, i.e.
   $$
   i{\rm E}[Y]=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\varphi_Y(z)\bigg|_{z=0}=i\int_Sf(x)\,\mu(\mathrm dx)
   $$
   and
   $$
   i^2{\rm E}[Y^2]=\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dz^2}\varphi_Y(z)\bigg|_{z=0}=i^2\int_Sf(x)^2\mu(\mathrm dx)+\left(i\int_Sf(x)\,\mu(\mathrm dx)\right)^2.
   $$
3. Use these expressions to find ${\rm E}[Y]$ and ${\rm Var}(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks! I tried a slightly different approach using the Laplace functional of the Poisson point process. But everything works with the Laplace functional.